# No compatible version found: draft-js-utils@^1.3.3

Tags: npm, npm-install, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

After recent update of draft-js-export-html 1.3.3 we are not able to compile the project as dependency is not found. We are getting below mentioned logs.

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: draft-js-utils@^1.3.3

npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:

npm ERR! notarget 1.3.2, 1.3.0, 1.2.4, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2

npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.

npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting

npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'draft-js-export-html'
npm ERR! notarget

Could you please help us to resolve?

NOte : - Same was working till yesterday. 27/2/2019

Answer (score 0):

please check on their github !
https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/issues/171

Comment: If you can pull out the relevant details from links then the information is preserved on Stack Overflow even if the link changes in the future :-)

Comment: It's fix now ;-)